# fineuploader doesn't display file chooser dialog

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, fine-uploader

I'm having an issue using FineUploader in my rails application. If I use the drag & drop method to upload files it works perfectly, but if I click the input it doesn't show the explorer window.

In my page, I have some fineUploader items defining:

```
    function createUploaders() {
        <% num.times do |x| %>
        $('#miSingle<%= x %>').fineUploader({
            request:{
                method: 'POST',
                endpoint: '<%= event_multimedia_items_path(event_id: params[:event_id]) %>'
            },
            multiple: false,
            text: {
                uploadButton: '<span>Drop files there</span>'
            },
            template: '<div class="qq-uploader span12">' +
                    '<pre class="qq-upload-drop-area span12"></pre>' +
                    '<div class="qq-upload-button" style="width: auto;">{uploadButtonText}</div>' +
                    '<span class="qq-drop-processing"><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>' +
                    '<ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>' +
                    '</div>',
            classes: {
                success: 'alert alert-success',
                fail: 'alert alert-error'
            },
            debug: true
        }).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                    if (responseJSON.success) {
                        $(this).empty();
                        var add = responseJSON;
                        $(this).append('<img src="' + responseJSON.thumb + '" alt="' + fileName + '">');
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("Error en la subida del archivo");
                        $(this).find('.qq-upload-list li').remove();
                    }
             });
    <% end %> 
}
window.onload = createUploaders;
```

I'm using twitter bootstrap and I've read that there's a problem with compatibility between bootstrap and fineuploader.

Versions:

fineuploader-3.5.0
bootstrap-2.3.2
jquery-1.9.1

Anybody can give me some directions please or solutions about this problem?

Comment: I will take a closer look at your code in an hour or two, but where did you read about this problem between bootstrap and the Uploader?  I'm not aware of any issues and, in fact, the bootstrapped demo on the home page works fine.

Comment: Works fine for me in Bootstrap 3.2.3.  Most likely, some other javascript or CSS in your project is causing you problems.  Are you seeing any javascript errors in the console?  Have you inspected the upload button element?  What does it look like in the DOM?  Also, the `request` option has no `method` property.

Comment: I think the problem is about bootstrap cause if a remove this javascript from application.js it works fine, but my problem is all over project use bootstrap functions :(

Comment: Dont have javascript errors. The upload element: 
<input multiple="multiple" type="file" name="file" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;">
It looks like fine, and if I put it outside fineUploader it works...

Comment: The issue is specific to your environment and code as Fine Uploader works fine with bootstrap both in my tests and on the home page demos.  You'll need to spend some time in developer tools to figure out which of your CSS rules or javascript is causing this issue.  If you have definitive proof of a Fine Uploadet bug, please file a bug report in the github repo.

Comment: I fixed it. It happened because there was an open div who called the modal view of bootstrap  and this stopped the jquery propagation for the file upload window
Thanks for the quick response

Comment: please explain your solution here in an official answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

It happened because there was an open div who called the modal view of bootstrap and this stopped the jquery propagation for the file upload window.

Thanks for the quick response